# Download .CSV file from basic webserver on Pico W

Tags: webserver, raspberry-pi-pico

I am trying to download a .CSV file from my Pico W that is running a very basic webserver and I want to download the file via a browser. I am at a point where I click a link on the served web page and it indicates a file has been downloaded but the file is just a .HTML when I look. I am very new to all this and I have been watching everything I can regarding this challenge but it seems that all people want to do is control LED's with a webserver and nobody has an example of file download. I have cobbled together the micropython code that seems to work to a point from lots of different online examples. Please forgive my ignorance but this seems like such a basic thing to be able to do. I do hope someone can help.

Here is the code I am currently using.

```py
# This code based on original code from Raspberry Pi
# Connecting to the internet with pico w doc
#

import network
import socket
import time

from machine import Pin
import uasyncio as asyncio

onboard = Pin("LED", Pin.OUT, value=0)

ssid = "SSID"
password = "PASWD"

html = """<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head> <title>Pico W</title>
    </head>
    <body> <h1>My Pico W</h1>
    <ims src="/leaf.jpg">
        <p>%s</p>
        
    </body>
</html>
"""

webdocs="/webroot/"

wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)

def connect_to_network():
    wlan.active(True)
    wlan.config(pm = 0xa11140) # Disable power-save mode
    wlan.connect(ssid, password)
    
    max_wait = 10
    while max_wait > 0:
        if wlan.status() < 0 or wlan.status() >= 3:
            break
        max_wait -= 1

        print('waiting for connection...')
        time.sleep(1)
    
    if wlan.status() != 3:
        raise RuntimeError('network connection failed')
    else:
        print('connected')
        status = wlan.ifconfig()

        print('ip = ' + status[0])


async def serve_client(reader, writer):
    print("Client connected")
    request_line = await reader.readline()
    print("Request:", request_line)
    
    # We are not interested in HTTP request headers, skip them
    while await reader.readline() != b"\r\n":
        pass
    
    
    request = str(request_line)
    css = request.find('.jpg')
    
    response = html
    
    if css > 0:
        
        requestedfile  = request[6:css+4]
        print("CSS requested:" + requestedfile)
        f = open(webdocs + requestedfile)
        response = f.read()
        f.close()
        
        writer.write('HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-type: image/jpg\r\n\r\n')
        writer.write(response)
    else:
        writer.write('HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-type: text/html\r\n\r\n')
        writer.write(response)

    
    await writer.drain()
    await writer.wait_closed()
    print("Client disconnected")
    
async def main():
    print('Connecting to Network...')
    connect_to_network()
    
    print('Setting up webserver...')
    asyncio.create_task(asyncio.start_server(serve_client, "0.0.0.0", 80))
    while True:
        onboard.on()
        print("heartbeat")
        await asyncio.sleep(0.25)
        onboard.off()
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        
try:
    asyncio.run(main())
finally:
    asyncio.new_event_loop()
```